# Finding a function which asymptotically goes to a constant and does not blow up at zero

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions

I have a function with the following behavior:
$$
f(0) = 1\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \alpha
$$
Here, $\alpha$ is a positive constant (say, 2).
The function $f$ is monotonically increasing and asymptotically approaching $\alpha$.
The plot between $l := \log(x)$ and $f$ is like a sigmoid function.
I tried fitting $f$ with the standard sigmoid functions of $l$, like logisitic, error, tan hyperbolic, arctan functions but nothing works good [The RMS error is significant with respect to variation in $f$]

See the graphs for reference.

[f as a function of log x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXjjP.jpg), [f as function of x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq52A.jpg)

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Btw $f(\infty)$ is a really bad notation, should do something like $\lim_{h \rightarrow \infty} f(h)$.

Comment: $$f(x)= \alpha +(1-\alpha) e^{-x}$$

Comment: @Prometheus Yes you are correct will update. Actually I am a physics student, so often there is abuse of notation.

Comment: @MarkViola This seems to work however the function increases faster than the set of values I have. I think with some modulation this could work. Thanks.

Comment: I know that haha, I also get lazy like this when I do Physics, but Maths is more "strict", in the sense that when I do math I get more serious about notation.

Comment: @MarkViola Unfortunately, I tried modulating the exponential term it does not work. The exponential drops to 1 rather quickly than the observed values. I need to `slow' the exponential down.

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, that is something I need to work on :)

Comment: What's the derivative in the log plot look like? The log plot just looks like a cumulative distribution function, so maybe you'd be able to find a probability density function that matches it.

Comment: I only provide you with a function that meets the criteria your wrote, namely $f(0)=1$, $f(\infty)=\alpha$, and $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fitting below.

The blue curve is the curve fitted to a set of points (red) taken by scanning your figure entitled " f as a function of log x ". Thus $X=$log x .

[image]

You wrote log x . If it is the Natural logarithm (base e) then the above formula is equivalent to
$$Y=a+\frac{b}{1+\gamma\:x^{-\delta}}\quad\text{with}\quad X=\ln(x)\quad;\quad\gamma=e^{c/d} \quad ;\quad \delta=1/d$$
If your log is another logaritm (different base than e) convert it first to put it into the formula.

NOTE : The data used above is :

X = -13.41 , -11.36 , -10.95 , -9.69 , -8.99 , -8.01 , -7.07 , -6.05 , -5.35 , -4.46 , -3.8 , -3.02 , -2.33 , -1.8 , -1.02 , -0.37 , 0.08 , 0.53 , 1.06 , 1.63 , 2.21 , 2.86 , 3.39 , 3.84 , 4.62 , 5.19 , 5.97 , 6.54 , 7.64 , 8.54 , 9.36 , 10.18 , 10.91 , 11.69 , 12.75 , 13.16

Y = 1.002 , 1.005 , 1.005 , 1.007 , 1.009 , 1.014 , 1.021 , 1.032 , 1.041 , 1.062 , 1.08 , 1.107 , 1.139 , 1.167 , 1.217 , 1.265 , 1.299 , 1.34 , 1.386 , 1.438 , 1.486 , 1.543 , 1.584 , 1.614 , 1.659 , 1.687 , 1.716 , 1.732 , 1.755 , 1.767 , 1.773 , 1.778 , 1.78 , 1.783 , 1.785 , 1.785

Comment: Thank you for the this, but unfortunately I have already tried this out ( logistic like polynomial). First, I am amazed that you scanned and collected the points. Second, the RMS error for this is of the order of $10^{-2}$. I managed to find a modified tan hyperbolic function which is slightly better, but still on the look out for a better fitting.

Comment: Without your data one cannot reproduce what you did with a sufficient accuracy So, it is not possible to improve the model and/or the method of regression in order to reach your goal. By the way your goal for a satisfory RMSE is not specified in the question which hence is ambiguous.

Comment: @Hridey I find JJacquelin's amount of effort remarkable. If even that is not enough precision for you, the problem lies entirely with your question and the vague data and constraints you've provided.

Comment: @Hridey. The above fitting (corresponding to the figure in my answer) leads to RMSE$\simeq 0.0025$ . This is much better than the results $\simeq 0.01$ mentioned in your comment. Why ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry for the ambiguity, actually I think I should have added the point set.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Yes, the effort is commendable, and I am very thankful.  I think that is because I calculated the RMS error with 10000 pts. Sorry if I came across as ungrateful.